# VS Code is not open in WSL -2 Ubuntu 18.04 server - giving command 'code' not found

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, wsl-2

I have give this type of error in wsl when I type code .

```
samanthika-137:~/repos/wams$ code .

Command 'code' not found, did you mean:

  command 'cde' from deb cde (0.1+git9-g551e54d-1.1build1)
  command 'cdde' from deb cdde (0.3.1-1build1)
  command 'ode' from deb plotutils (2.6-10build1)
  command 'node' from deb nodejs (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1)
  command 'tcode' from deb emboss (6.6.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue caused because of window update and disconnect.
I have done these steps

1. Go to ubuntu home directory and delete . vscode-server
   [image]
2. Then go to setting -> Apps -> search ubuntu->go to advanced options -> Reset -> Repair

[image]

3. The go to run and type `service.msc`

[image]

4. Go to LxssManager and right click and restart
   [image]
5. Now go to the ubuntu terminal and type `code .`
   It will download vs code and it works

Comment: When i follow these steps my LxssManager is not running

Answer (score 1):

reinstall Ubuntu Software:

```bash
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Clean the Cache:

```bash
sudo apt clean
```

update and upgrade:

```bash
sudo apt update
```